# GPPSignIn iOS Failing

Tags: ios, oauth-2.0, google-plus

I am trying to integrate google plus sign in into an iOS application. I have set up credentials for my application, added a url type with my application's bundle id, and followed the instructions detailed in google's developer documentation.

In my ViewController:

- In the header file I have declared the ViewController as a `<GPPSignInDelegate>`
- In the .m file I have created variable `kClientId` with my clientId from the developer portal
- In the `viewDidLoad` method I have added the following:

  ```
  [GPPSignIn sharedInstance].clientID = kClientId;
  [GPPSignIn sharedInstance].scopes = @[ @"profile"];
  [GPPSignIn sharedInstance].shouldFetchGoogleUserEmail = YES;
  [GPPSignIn sharedInstance].delegate = self;
  ```
- In my sign in button click handler I call

  ```
  [[GPPSignIn sharedInstance] authenticate]
  ```
- I have implemented the methods

  `finishedWithAuth:(GTMOAuth2Authentication *)auth error:(NSError *)error`

  and

  `(void)presentViewController:(UIViewController *)viewControllerToPresent animated:(BOOL)flag completion:(void (^)(void))completion`

In my AppDelegate I have added the following:

```
- (BOOL)application: (UIApplication *)application
        openURL: (NSURL *)url sourceApplication: (NSString *)sourceApplication
         annotation: (id)annotation { 
            return [GPPURLHandler handleURL:url 
                    sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                    annotation:annotation]; }
```

The return value for this method is always "NO" and the GPPSignIn delegate method

```
finishedWithAuth:(GTMOAuth2Authentication *)auth error:(NSError *)error
```

is never called. My application redirects to the sign in page and upon signing in shows no error code but simply redirects back to the original view in my application. I have checked the `[[GPPSignIn sharedInstance] hasAuthInKeychain]` property after the sign in and it is false. I've checked in the AppDelegate.m that the GPPSignInDelegate is set to my view controller, and it is. After looking through some posts I played around with making a class level variable for the `[[GPPSignIn sharedInstance]` value but no matter what the result is the same. Can anyone tell me what I am missing here?

Comment: Visit Here    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25238221/ios-google-signin-finishedwithauth-not-called-after-application-openurl-delegat/30730791#30730791