# iOS Google+ SignIn finishedWithAuth not called after application openURL delegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-plus

`iOS Google+ SignIn finishedWithAuth` never triggered after the `application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:` app delegate method. This was working, but now it does not.

The response is:

```
url:com.**************:/oauth2callback?state=19139956&code=4/<some token string>&authuser=0&num_sessions=1&prompt=consent&session_state=9efdca9285835ed58ace73b284e4f7521076fc97..4291*
```

The `signIn` instance is a class member, so I don't know what happens for the `finishedWithAuth` triggering.

Thanks!

Comment: please check this Link:-
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48075914/voidfinishedwithauthgtmoauth2authentication-auth-errornserror-error

Answer (score 2):

```
  -(void)googlePluseLogin
{
    GPPSignIn *signIn  = [GPPSignIn sharedInstance];
    signIn.delegate = self;
    signIn.shouldFetchGooglePlusUser = YES;
    signIn.shouldFetchGoogleUserEmail = YES;
    signIn.clientID = kClientID;
    signIn.scopes = @[@"profile"];
    if (![signIn trySilentAuthentication])
        [signIn authenticate];
}

-(void)finishedWithAuth:(GTMOAuth2Authentication *)auth error:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"%@",auth);

    if (error)
    {

    }
    else
    {
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `GPPURLHandler handleURL` in your `application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:` method, and you need to have setup the delegate on `[GPPSignIn sharedInstance]` before. I am guessing that you don't set the delegate until after the GPPURLHandler has been processed.

Comment: The problem was, I did not handle correctly the URL response because I have Facebook login process to. :)

Comment: And to answer for your answer, I setted before the delegate controller object for GPPSignIn object, it was good, so I can not accept your answer but thanks for your assistance.

Comment: how application come back after sharing on google plus.

Comment: It comes back by the G+ app calling openURL with the custom URL scheme matching your bundle ID or reversed client ID.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to setup a URL Type as shown in [Step 3](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/getting-started)