# -(void)finishedWithAuth:(GTMOAuth2Authentication *)auth error:(NSError *)error -- Method is not call

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to get fetch user's all information who logged in with Google+ in my app.

```
-(void)googleSignInButtonMethod{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    signIn = [GPPSignIn sharedInstance];
    signIn.clientID = kClientId;
    [signIn authenticate];
    signIn.shouldFetchGoogleUserID=YES;
    signIn.shouldFetchGoogleUserEmail = YES;
    signIn.scopes = @[ kGTLAuthScopePlusLogin ];
    signIn.delegate = self;
    [signIn authenticate];
}
```

after that,

```
- (void)finishedWithAuth:(GTMOAuth2Authentication *)auth
                   error:(NSError *)error {

    NSLog(@"Received Error %@  and auth object==%@",error,auth);
    if(!error) {
        NSLog(@"%@", signIn.authentication.userEmail);
    }
}
```

I followed all the instruction provided by google+ developers site. I set all the delegates and import all important files.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**In .h file**

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet GIDSignInButton *gmailSignInButton;
-(IBAction)gmailBtn:(GIDSignIn *)sender;
```

**In .m file**

```
- (IBAction)gmailBtn:(GIDSignIn *)sender {
 [[AFNetworkReachabilityManager sharedManager]startMonitoring];

//Checking the Internet connection...
[[AFNetworkReachabilityManager sharedManager]setReachabilityStatusChangeBlock:^(AFNetworkReachabilityStatus status){
    if (status == AFNetworkReachabilityStatusReachableViaWWAN || status == AFNetworkReachabilityStatusReachableViaWiFi) {

        [GIDSignIn sharedInstance].uiDelegate = self;
        [[GIDSignIn sharedInstance] signIn];

    }else{
        NSLog(@"No Network");
    }
 }];
}

- (void)signIn:(GIDSignIn *)signIn didSignInForUser:(GIDGoogleUser *)user withError:(NSError *)error {
 // Perform any operations on signed in user here.
 NSLog(@"user ID: %@",user.userID);
 NSLog(@"user Token: %@",user.authentication.idToken);
 NSLog(@"user name: %@",user.profile.name);
 NSLog(@"user givenName: %@",user.profile.givenName);
 NSLog(@"user family Name: %@",user.profile.familyName);
 NSLog(@"user email: %@",user.profile.email);

 NSURL *profileURL;
 if (user.profile.hasImage)
 {
    profileURL = [user.profile imageURLWithDimension:100];
 }

 NSMutableDictionary *userData = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
 [userData setValue:user.userID forKey:@"id"];
 [userData setValue:user.profile.givenName forKey:@"first_name"];
 [userData setValue:user.profile.familyName forKey:@"last_name"];
 [userData setValue:@"" forKey:@"gender"];
 [userData setValue:user.profile.email forKey:@"email"];
 [userData setValue:profileURL forKey:@"profileImg"];    
}

- (void)signInWillDispatch:(GIDSignIn *)signIn error:(NSError *)error{
//    [self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void)signIn:(GIDSignIn *)signIn presentViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
   [self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}

// Dismiss the "Sign in with Google" view
 - (void)signIn:(GIDSignIn *)signIn dismissViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
   [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

> *don't forget to declare gmail delegate GIDSignInUIDelegate,GIDSignInDelegate